# Trying to use an external css for php html code

Tags: php, html, css

I am still new to this area.

I am trying to style my PHP into a table and change font, color etc using HTML and external CSS file but have been trying without success. Here's my current code;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Theatre CO887</title>
<H1>Theatre CO887</H1>
<H2> Upcoming shows</H2>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$host = 'mysite.uk';
$dbname = 'mydb';
$user = 'abcdefg';
$pwd = '12345';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pwd); 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "select * from Production"; 
    $handle = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $handle->execute(); 
    $conn = null;

    $res = $handle->fetchAll(); 
    foreach($res as $row) { 
        echo "<li>".$row['Title']." - ".$row['BasicTicketPrice']."</li>";
}
}       catch (PDOException $e) { 
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS so far...

```
<style>
body {
background-color: powderblue;
}
h1 {
color: blue;
}
p {
color: red;
}
</style>
```

I just really need to know how to add table structure to include the selected data in my PHP in my HTML then style it through CSS.

Basically, I have to have a .css file and .php. But formatting the data from PHP is just beyond me somewhat. Thanks.

Comment: Is the stylesheet's path correct? Looks like it should be in the site's root directory? Is it there?

Comment: Side note : I sure hope those aren't actual credentials.

Comment: What is the issue? Can the css file not be found (check the browser console)?

Comment: there's nothing in what you posted that suggests any styling attributes, unless your stylesheet is only targeting `<li>`, that's unknown.

Comment: *"I am trying to style my PHP into a table and change font"* - If you mean "HTML" table, I don't see those or fonts or anything else really. Voting to close.

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. [This](https://validator.nu) will show the errors in your HTML. [This](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) will show any errors in your CSS … which you failed to include in the question. You must provide a [mcve]. Use the Developer Tools in your browser. The Network tab will tell you if the CSS file is being requested and if you are getting the CSS you expect or something else (like a 404 error).

Answer (score 0):

See here for html table structure:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

You use the Tryit Editor to play with your css styles

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Theatre CO887</title>
<H1>Theatre CO887</H1>
<H2> Upcoming shows</H2>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
<?php
$host = 'mysite.uk';
$dbname = 'mydb';
$user = 'abcdefg';
$pwd = '12345';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pwd); 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "select * from Production"; 
    $handle = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $handle->execute(); 
    $conn = null;

    $res = $handle->fetchAll(); 
    foreach($res as $row) { 
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['Title']."</td><td>".$row['BasicTicketPrice']."</td></tr>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in the css:

```
table
{
border: 1px solid black;
}

tr
{
..table row styles..

{

td
{
..table cell styles..

}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! Now how do I add a column title of my choice to the table? and a radio button by each row? Thanks in advance

Comment: For the column headers, create a row and the <th> tag for each column: <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>. This is all in the example I linked to on w3schools.com. For radio buttons, see here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Thank you. But the buttons will need to be next to each corresponding line of the table (outside the table) so next to it. I cant find a way of positioning them outside the PHP code and getting the buttons in the position I want, eventually, they will need to be functional buttons that work when a user selects a button that has a function associated with PHP connecting to MySql. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to put them in the php code - presumably in a column in your table. You need to read and understand the code and the documentation. This site is not for people to write the code for you. It is for people to help you when you are stuck. Have a go - if you have a problem, post your attempt at some code - don't just ask for it to be done for you!